# Need to click on Pause button on tapping on video while doing getting error

Tags: selenium

Need to click on Pause button on tapping on video while doing getting error.

Error as:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (25, 312). Other element would receive the click.

XPATH:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='togglepaused']/descendant::i[@class='fa fa-pause']")).click();
```

Html Code:

```
<button class="toggle-paused"> <i class="fa fa-pause"> ::before </i> </button>
```

[image]

Comment: Html Code:
<button class="toggle-paused">
    <i class="fa fa-pause"> ::before </i>
</button>
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: There is a typo: you need to use `@class='toggle-paused'` instead of `@class='togglepaused'`

Comment: Have you tried something simple like XPath: "//button[@class='toggle-paused']"?

Comment: hi JeffC used //button[@class='toggle-paused'] but getting same error